# LED Poster configuration

Tags: led, batteries, resistors

I am helping my sister make a LED poster for a concert she is going to. I am using a foam board with some letters she placed on there. I am then going to add LED's on top of the letters to spell them out so you can read them from a distance.

The LED's I have on hand are:

Light Color : White;Forward Voltage : 3.2 - 3.4V

Luminous Intensity : 10000 - 12000MCD;Main Color : Silver Tone, Clear

There will be a total of about 60 LED's on the sign. My questions are, what type of circuit do I need for this? I currently have a battery pack that take 3 double A batteries but not sure if that will be enough.

Any thoughts on the best way to go about doing this? I estimate the sign will be on for ~2 hours. She can take another set of batteries with her if needed.

Thanks for any advice you can provide!

**EDIT:** Here is a link to the LED's that I have. [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0087ZT06U?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=od_aui_detailpages01](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087ZT06U)

**UPDATE 2**

Here are some images of the Power box I have:

[image]

[image]

This is the only pack of resistors I can find in the house. This is a last minute project and a lot of radio shacks have closed near me. Not sure If I can do anything with this :/

[image]

Comment: What is the forward current of the LEDs given as, nominally?

Comment: @stefandz I'm not sure I understand the question :x. What I see on the box I have is "Forward Voltage : 3.2 - 3.4V".

Comment: That's OK - all LEDs have both a forward voltage and a current at that voltage. It's part of what distinguishes low power and high power LEDs. Do you have a link to where you purchased them and / or some images of them? It might help people narrow the current down. If you do, please pop them into the question by editing it, not in the comments where people might miss it.

Comment: Thanks, @stefandz! I updated the OP with the link to where I purchased the LED's from. Hope it helps!

Comment: Boost switching LED driver.

Answer (score 2):

From the link you have posted it's not possible to be 100% sure of the forward current, but I'm going to guess they would be good for 20mA and still visible at 10mA. With that in mind...

The forward voltage of the LED is around 3.3V - three AA batteries gives 4.5V maximum. Therefore with one 3xAA pack you would have to wire this circuit 60 times in parallel to the batteries (I have shown this twice below - I really don't have the time for 60!). I have conservatively chosen the current to be 10mA, which should be enough for this to be visible.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiKJk6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will be a big pain in the butt wiring-wise, and not particularly efficient. Run time will be in the region of 4 hours though, which is nice.

An alternative, which reduces the amount of wiring would be to use 2x 3AA battery packs in series. Now, at a total of 9V we can't really get away with 3 LEDs in a row (3x 3.3V = 9.9V > 9V), so we'll be stuck with two, but it means you have less wiring to do. See the schematic below (this time 30 repeats would be required - again, I only show 2).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJncDn.png)</sup>

The current this time is around 11mA per LED (due to there being fixed basic resistor values and 240 Ohms not being one of them) but the overall effect will be similar. Run time will be around twice as long this way, as you might expect. You could reduce the series resistors down to 120 Ohms and get brighter LEDs, but drop back nearer the 4 hour mark for battery life.

There are other options such as using a boost circuit to increase the voltage from the 4.5V battery pack to around 12V and run parallel strings of 3 LEDs, but I think the circuits I have shown probably fit your skillset and motivation best. If it were me, I would plump for the second option.

Comment: Silly question but would a 9v battery be the same as the 2  3AA packs equaling 9v?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude or snarky, but go on, what's your guess?

Comment: The total voltage is the same, I get that but wasn't sure if the resistors suggested on the AA's would change when doing it with a single 9v

Comment: OK, well the voltage isn't the issue, but the capacity of the battery is lower, by about a factor of 4. So - the 9V battery will last about 2 hours (with the 220 Ohm resistors), but only just. If I were going this route I would probably take a spare battery with me.

Comment: Stefandz has hiven you a great answer. your option re battery could also be to use 6v lantern types. but beware many concert venues have strict security about this sort of stuff. Would hate for you to spend hrs making it to have it confiscated at the door....

Comment: Not sure of the leds are the cause here but I tried a simple circuit of two leds and the battery pack and it doesn't work with multiple. A single led works fine but not more than one. There is a resistor in this battery pack with the colors "green purple gold gold". Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Is it possible the first gold band is yellow? If so then you have a 570k resistor. what battery pack are you using? it does not sound like a standard aa unit.

Comment: It's very odd that there is a resistor already in the battery pack. Could you please attach lots of good images of it to the original question so that we can work out what is going on.

Comment: @stefandz I have updated the OP with some pics. I found a pack of resistors at home but they may not work at all. This is a last minute project so I may not be able to accomplish this with the stuff on hand. Out of the resistors pictured in the last image, 4 of the 3AA battery packs or 9 volt batteries is there anything I can do to get this working with the poster of about ~60 leds?

Comment: Sadly not with any degree of control. The resistors you have are far too large - you would need 10 of each in parallel to simulate one of the resistors I specified - i.e. 300 resistors at 9V or 600 at 4.5V. The series resistor in your power pack suggests it is a low-cost attempt to be an LED driver for a particular LED string - that resistor looks like a 1 or 2 Watt rated 470 Ohm resistor to me. If you can get out to an electronics shop and purchase the parts I specified you will be fine - otherwise sadly this may become a project for another time.